# How to move files depending on something to specific folders

Tags: windows, file-management

My music library contains a complete folder structure. 
For example:

`Classical Music\Mozart\Karajan\Sonatas\music.mp3`

I would like to move the `music.mp3` one level up. I do have however thousands of Folders so it is not feasable to select each folder search for *.* cut and paste the files to the "upper" folder.
Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Take a look here: [DOS batch command to move all files in last subdirectory one level up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18289626/3439404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can write a script to do this with something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/).

This supports iterating through a directory structure and acting on the files that it finds.

It isn't difficult to knock up a script to copy files just as you describe.